# Spring Boot API repeating SQL data incorrectly

Tags: java, mysql, api, maven, spring-boot

**I have an API from Spring-boot that connects successfully to my SQL database.
I have a large data set {224} and the data displayed from the get request repeats.**

**It repeats the first 7 items correctly, then repeats them then adds the 15 slot correctly, then it has a mixture of reapeating the first 7 items and the 15 slot for the remaining slots.**

Any help on this would be appreciated as im stumped. :( 
**I've included all the code that might help below.**

The issue is that the card data for each 224 cards are differenent, and they are correct in mysql, but when looking at the data in the springboot API with the GET function, the data repeats the first elemenets of the cards which is incorrect. Nothing in the mysql data is a key, the id,imglocation,name columns are unique strings(and all different) but this isnt stated in the SQL table

**Card.java**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cards")
public class Card {

    @Id

    String clan;
    int cost;
    int decklimit;
    String element;
    int fate;
    int glory;
    int honor;
    String id;
    String imglocation;
    int influencecost;
    int influencepool;
    String isrestricted;
    int military;
    String militarybonus;
    String name;
    int political;
    String politicalbonus;
    String rolerestriction;
    String side;
    int strength;
    String strengthbonus;
    String text;
    String typeof;
    String unicity;
```

GETTERS AND SETTERS REDACTED

**Card Repository**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.name.models.Card;

public interface CardRepository extends JpaRepository<Card, String>{


}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9000

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://{IP-redacted}:3306/{SQL-table-name-redacted}?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=redacted
spring.datasource.password=redacted

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Card Controller**

```
import com.name.repository.CardRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.name.models.Card;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class CardController {

    @Autowired
    private CardRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "cards", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Card> listAllCards(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

**MYSQL TABLE**

```
 Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| clan            | varchar(8)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cost            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| decklimit       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| element         | varchar(5)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| fate            | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| glory           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| honor           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id              | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| imglocation     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| influencecost   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| influencepool   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| isrestricted    | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| military        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| militarybonus   | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name            | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| political       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| politicalbonus  | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rolerestriction | varchar(6)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| side            | varchar(8)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| strength        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| strengthbonus   | varchar(2)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| text            | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| typeof          | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| unicity         | varchar(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

DATA

```
`[{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crane","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"shizuka-toshi","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_2.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shizuka Toshi","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a [conflict-political] conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a participating character with [conflict-political] skill 2 or lower - bow that character.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"dragon","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"mountain-s-anvil-castle","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_3.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Mountain's Anvil Castle","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a participating character with 1 or more attachments on it - until the end of the conflict, that character gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] (+2[conflict-military] and +2[conflict-political] instead if it has 2 or more attachments on it).","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"lion","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":12,"id":"yojin-no-shiro","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_4.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Y?jin no Shiro","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each attacking character you control gets +1[conflict-military] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"phoenix","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"isawa-mori-seido","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_5.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Isawa Mori Seid?","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> Bow this stronghold, choose a character - that character gets +2 glory until the end of the phase.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"scorpion","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"city-of-the-open-hand","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_6.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"City of the Open Hand","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+1","text":"<b>Action:</b> If you are less honorable than an opponent, bow this stronghold and select one - either that opponent loses 1 honor, or you gain 1 honor.\n<i>Errata from RRG v9</i>","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"unicorn","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"golden-plains-outpost","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_7.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Golden Plains Outpost","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+0","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a [conflict-military] conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a <em>Cavalry</em> character you control - move it to that conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"crane","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"shizuka-toshi","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_2.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shizuka Toshi","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a [conflict-political] conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a participating character with [conflict-political] skill 2 or lower - bow that character.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"dragon","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"mountain-s-anvil-castle","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_3.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Mountain's Anvil Castle","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a participating character with 1 or more attachments on it - until the end of the conflict, that character gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] (+2[conflict-military] and +2[conflict-political] instead if it has 2 or more attachments on it).","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"lion","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":12,"id":"yojin-no-shiro","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_4.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Y?jin no Shiro","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each attacking character you control gets +1[conflict-military] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"phoenix","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"isawa-mori-seido","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_5.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Isawa Mori Seid?","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> Bow this stronghold, choose a character - that character gets +2 glory until the end of the phase.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"scorpion","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"city-of-the-open-hand","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_6.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"City of the Open Hand","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+1","text":"<b>Action:</b> If you are less honorable than an opponent, bow this stronghold and select one - either that opponent loses 1 honor, or you gain 1 honor.\n<i>Errata from RRG v9</i>","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"unicorn","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"golden-plains-outpost","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_7.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Golden Plains Outpost","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+0","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a [conflict-military] conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a <em>Cavalry</em> character you control - move it to that conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},`{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},`{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},`{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},`{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},{"clan":"neutral","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"earth","fate":0,"glory":0,"honor":0,"id":"ancestral-lands","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_15.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":0,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Ancestral Lands","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":5,"strengthbonus":"","text":"This province gets +5 strength during [conflict-political] conflicts.","typeof":"province","unicity":"false"},`{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},`{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crab","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":10,"id":"shiro-nishiyama","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_1.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shiro Nishiyama","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+3","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a conflict, bow this stronghold - each defending character you control gets +1[conflict-military] and +1[conflict-political] until the end of the conflict.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"},{"clan":"crane","cost":0,"decklimit":1,"element":"","fate":7,"glory":0,"honor":11,"id":"shizuka-toshi","imglocation":"http://lcg-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/l5r/L5C01_2.jpg","influencecost":0,"influencepool":10,"isrestricted":"false","military":0,"militarybonus":"","name":"Shizuka Toshi","political":0,"politicalbonus":"","rolerestriction":"","side":"province","strength":0,"strengthbonus":"+2","text":"<b>Action:</b> During a [conflict-political] conflict, bow this stronghold. Choose a participating character with [conflict-political] skill 2 or lower - bow that character.","typeof":"stronghold","unicity":"true"}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it is not clear what the issue is. Not sure what repeating items and slots mean in this context. Would you be able to elaborate on the problem ? What is the expected result ? What is it that you are seeing ?

Comment: Can you show us actual data? Is clan field a primary key in your db. Is it unique?

Comment: Data has been added to show how they look like as JSON objects - this is where i see the issues - as you can see - the data are being repeated "shiro nishiyama" for example.

Comment: Can you please share the data available in db. Thank you

Comment: The issue is that the card data for each 224 cards are differenent, and they are correct in mysql, but when looking at the data in the springboot API with the GET function, the data repeats the first elemenets of the cards which is incorrect.                          Nothing in the mysql data is a key, the id,imglocation,name columns are unique strings(and all different) but this isnt stated in the SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

The @id was picking up 'clan' and not 'id'.

```
@Id
    String id;
```